# Google Plus and Google Contacts with Python

Tags: python, django, google-plus, google-contacts-api

My problem is the following:

I want to obtain information from my Google Contacts using the Google Plus API.

I already have a working implementation of Google+ using Python. So if I know a certain user's ID, I can access the resource and obtain their name, email, and all that. All good up to this point.

However, I want to access the list of all my contacts. What I mean is, on GMail, when I navigate my contact list, I can see all my contacts with all their emails, display information, and Google+ ID.

How can I programatically, using my Google account, obtain a list of all my contacts' IDs, so that I can obtain the Google+ Person resource for each of them?

A very ugly way would naturally to scrape the HTML, but I definitely do not want to do that.

I found no reference to this in the documentation.

Thank you

Comment: Is it only for your self? You just want to get information about your contacts? Their G+ profiles

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to fetch a list of people you have circled from the Google+ API.  As far as GMail contacts, that is not within the realm of the Google+ API at this time. However, you can and should make these feature requests in our Issue Tracker, which you can find at https://developers.google.com/+/support.